# css set div pos, without margin-top and <br/>

Tags: css

How can I set a `<div>` position without `<br/>` and `margintop`? For e.g. `margin-top: 40px`?

HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="div_page">
    <div id="login" class="div_login">
        asd
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    div.div_login {
        background-color:#EAEAEA;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Learn position http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: There are many ways, like `top`, `padding-top`, `<br>` (just kidding about br) and setting the `height` and `bottom` (;

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have the div positioned relatively and use `top:40px`

```
div.div_login {
    background-color:#EAEAEA;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:40px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
position: relative;
```

To your div.div_login